# Using a user input for the area of a rectangle, find all possible length and width combinations (in Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.4, factors

I must  ask the user to input data for the x- and y- coordinate
of the point on a graph and the area of the rectangle. Then I have to calculate and print all the different possibilities of rectangles that can be constructed from those data. Then I have to show the x-and y-coordinate of the original point and the x- and y- coordinates of the opposite corner. I can do most of this, but the factoring of the length and width of rectangle(s) from the area (must be int) has left me scratching my head. Must be done with loops or statements, no new or separate functions other than main.

This is what I have done, but then I run into an error, the list is empty... It ran as intended though up to that point:

```
`for j in range(0, len(factors)):

    l = factors[0]
    w = factors[-1]

    # Calculate the x- and y-coordinate of the 1st rectangle using the width and the length

    first = (x + w,y + l)
    print ("The First Rectangle is the one which is constructed between the point", original_coordinate, "and", first)
    print ("")

    # Step 7. Calculate the x- and y-coordinate of the 2nd rectangle using the width and the length
    second = (x - w,y + l)
```

and at the end of the for loop, after the eighth possible rectangle, it then moves on to the next factor pair and discards the first set, so on and so on:

```
    factors.pop(-1)
    factors.pop(0)
```

Comment: Are the rectangle's dimensions limited to integer values?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Looks like you know how to get the different rectangles, just not how to store them.

Comment: The indentation you insist on is not valid Python code, by the way. That `if` statement is expecting an indented block.

Comment: I left out a print statement, sorry, I will edit again.  Other than storing them in a list, no, I am not sure how...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing them in a `list`. Try that out.

Comment: Of course, you'll have to fix your code snippet to have the necessary indented block after the `if` statement, and possibly include the decrement somewhere in the `while` so that it isn't infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
while len(factors)>0:

    l = factors[0]
    w = factors[-1]

    print("The eight possibilites for the lenghth of", l, "and the width of", w, "are: ")
    print()

    first = (x + w,y + l)

    print ("The First Rectangle is the one which is constructed between the point", original_coordinate, "and", first)
    print ("")
```

Etc. Tigerhawk, just read you last comment, that was what made me think of the while instead of for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
area = 12 # comes from input
possibilities = [] # initialize a list
for length in range (1, area+1): # go through every possible length
    width, invalid = divmod(area, length) # find the width and its validity
    if not invalid: # if there's no remainder
        possibilities.append((length, width)) # add this
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
possibilities = [(length, width) for length, (width, invalid) in
                 ((length, divmod(area, length)) for length in
                 range(1, area+1)) if not invalid]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(*possibilities, sep='\n') # print the possible rectangles
(1, 12)
(2, 6)
(3, 4)
(4, 3)
(6, 2)
(12, 1)
```

Comment: Ooh, nice use of `divmod`.